# Checkboxes in a DataGrid get selected after Scrolling down in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

i have implemented code, where i put Checkboxes in a DataGrid. The problem is, when a checkbox is checked and i scroll down, other checkboxes are checked as well, without me having checked them. If i scroll up again, the checkbox, which i initially checked, isnt checked anymore. Can anybody help me please.

Here is the Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    initialize="main()" textAlign="right" textRotation="rotate270" title="HomeView">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.collections.ArrayList;
            import mx.graphics.SolidColorStroke;

            import spark.primitives.Rect;
            import spark.skins.spark.DefaultComplexItemRenderer;
            import spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer;
            private var bL:ArrayList;

            public function main():void{


            hey.dataProvider=dataprovider;      
            }




        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:ArrayList id="dataprovider">


            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2" name="1"/>
                <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55" name="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2" name="3"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55" name="4"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2" name="1"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55" name="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2" name="3"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55" name="4"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2" name="1"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55" name="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2" name="3"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55" name="4"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact1" actnumber="2"/>
            <fx:Object actName="myact2" actnumber="55"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:DataGrid id="hey" x="-2" y="-1" width="323" height="415">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>

                <s:GridColumn id="my" dataField="wierd">

                </s:GridColumn>

                <s:GridColumn id="hi" dataField="checkboxes">

                    <s:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:GridItemRenderer>

                                <fx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
            protected function checkbox1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                                        {
                                    trace("clicked");
                                        }
                                    ]]>
                                </fx:Script>

                <s:CheckBox click="checkbox1_clickHandler(event)">

                                </s:CheckBox>
                            </s:GridItemRenderer>

                        </fx:Component>

                    </s:itemRenderer>

                </s:GridColumn>

            </s:ArrayList>

        </s:columns>



    </s:DataGrid>
   </s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to fix this issue. ( a work around )

The reason for this has something to do with the way it is implemented inside the `Datagrid`.

Eg: When you create 50 rows inside the `Datagrid`. It does not create 50 different instances of the row.. ( in a scrolling scenario ) rather, as you scroll up or down the same rows are populated with the differing data..( giving you a seamless experience of scrolling and viewing them )

So the trick to solving this problem would be to study the sample found in this link

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/attachment.php3?attachmentid=38409&d=1335099663

You would have to analyse the code in the cell renderer class found in the sample. In your case you would have to modify the `DefaultItemRenderer` or the `DefaultComplexItemRenderer` which ever is used by the `Datagrid` column.